# Use ListFragment in DialogFragment?

Tags: android

I have a button that should a open a dialog where the user can enter some text in a search field and the app will asynchronously search the db (using ContentProvider?) every time a key is entered. The results are displayed in a ListView below the the EditText.

The CursorLoader sample and most other samples that I found never use a DialogFragment but either an Activity, FragmentActivity or ListFragment. This sample uses a method setListAdapter() which is not available in DialogFragment.

Can I use a DialogFragment directly for what I need or do I need to use a ListFragment within a DialogFragment?

Furthermore, I do the following:

```
    editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String search = new String(s.toString());

            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }
    });
```

However, `this` is not a valid LoaderCallback. How do I access the DialogFragment?

Comment: you can use a DialogFragment directly.

Comment: use getActivity() in the place of this.

Comment: It's the DialogFragment that implements LoaderCallbacks.

Comment: then use your-dialog-fragment-classname.this instead of just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom view containing a ListView in your DialogFragment. This will allow you to add an EditText and manipulate the ListView

```
public class ExampleFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null); //inflate some view that contains a ListView
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView); //get a reference to your ListView

    listView.setAdapter(...); //you can use the same methods as ListFragment to manipulate your list
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getActivity()` instead of `this`  keyword